# FFmpeg HEVC -crf attribute

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I am using FFMPEG version *20140406-git-59c1023-win32-static* with the following cmd

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\1.mkv" -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -preset veryslow "C\2.mkv"
```

The produced output filesize from running this cmd is 46mb

If I change the *-crf* from 18 to 26 then re-encode, the filesize output will also be 46mb.
Whatever integer I provide for *-crf*, 18, 26, 40, 45 etc, the time taken to perform this encode is the same, the output filesize is the same, and the quality in the video is the same.

Seems like it doesn't work.

I have tried to move the parameters around, this does not cause anything different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-crf` option probably has not been mapped yet for this encoder. Until then use `-x265-params` private option for this encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec:v libx265 -x265-params crf=28 -codec:a copy out.mkv
```

This may change in the future, so always refer to the documentation first:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265
```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg: How to generate a .mp4 with h.265 Codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505783/1109017)

Comment: Perhaps the same is true for -preset veryslow also? I did not think that that could also be broke.

Comment: @user348076 `-preset veryslow` should work without using `-x265-params`, at least according to the x265 documentation.